# When is true that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\partial A\subseteq B$?

Tags: general-topology

I try to understand when if $B$ is subset of $A$ then $\partial B$ is subset of the same.

Generally I think that if $B\subseteq A$ then is not $\partial B\subseteq A$, but if $B\subseteq\overset{\,\,\,\circ}A$ or $B\subseteq\overline A=A$ or $B\subseteq\partial A$ then it could be true? So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even  if $B \subseteq A^{0}$ it may not be true that $\partial B \subseteq A$. Example $A=B=(0,1)$.

If $A$ is closed then the conclusion is true: $\partial B \subseteq \overline {B} \subseteq \overline {A}=A$

Comment: You say that if $A$ is closed the inclusion is true: could you prove it, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes,I have done that.

Comment: Right, it was simple! And finally if $B\subseteq\partial A$ then the inclusion could not be true, right?

Comment: It is possible for $\partial B $ to be contained in $A$ even if $A$ is not closed and $B$ is contained in the interior of $A$. Ex: $B=\{0\}$ and $A=(0,1)$. It is not possible to give a necessary and sufficient condition. @AntonioMariaDiMauro

Comment: Okay, thanks too much for your assistance! Then could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787846/if-s-subseteq-bbb-rn-is-compact-and-rectifiable-then-pi-bbb-rms-is-r), please?